# Classloader refusing access to AudioPlayer

Tags: security, classloader, java

I copied the text of my program to another computer, but there is some problem with importing `sun.audio.AudioPlayer` class. The compiler underlines the importing string and when I place mouse over it, there is this text, which I can't quite understand:

> Access restriction: The type `AudioPlayer` is not accessible due to restriction on required library `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/rt.jar`

What does that mean, and how can I get rid of it? :S

Comment: Have you given permission to the folder which contains this jar?

Comment: The folder in which you have all the jar, from command line run ls -l

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to configure your eclipse to use openjdk as described [here](http://ianma.wordpress.com/2010/05/03/access-restriction-java-openjdk-rt-jar/)

Comment: where should i find JRE System Library? :S i can't see it in eclipse? :S

Comment: Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs

Comment: i can't see build path there... :S

Comment: Just select the root library of your JRE / JDK in /usr/lib/... . Eclipse should find the library path by itself.

Comment: i did it :S now my package is java-6-sun-1.6.0.24 :S but it still doesn't work :S

Comment: Did you set the actual JRE as default one? Or delete no more used JRE configurations in this window? Also you might need to do a rebuild (Project -> Clean with the actual project selected) after changing the JRE.

Answer (score 2):

This error message can be removed by changing a setting inside Eclipse IDE. Open up the dialog box shown below, using any of the following paths.

Windows(Command + ,) -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Errors/Warnings
Project(Command + I) -> Properties -> Java Compiler -> Errors/Warnings

Locate the “Forbidden reference (access rules)” option under “Deprecated and restricted API” section in the dialog box. This option decides how to handle access rules defined inside Eclipse. By default it is set to “Error” which causes Eclipse to complain about references to any restricted classes. Choosing any other option (Warning or Ignore) will remove these error messages.

“Warning” or “Ignore” options will only hide the potential issue in the project, by allowing the project to use any classes ignoring predefined access rules. To completely resolve this issue, analyze the project and located the use of restricted classes and take necessary actions (either remove those references or access rules).

Answer (score 0):

Or just remove / reeadd same JDK. Worked for me.